# Is there any way to create a primitive array without initialization?

Tags: java, arrays

As we know Java always initialises arrays upon creation. I.e. `new int[1000000]` always returns an array with all elements = 0. I understand that it's a must for Object arrays, but for primitive arrays (except may be Boolean) in most cases we don't care about the initial values.

Does anybody know a way to avoid this intialization?

Comment: No, you can't avoid it. That's how it works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. All primitives have a default value. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What would you have Java put in the place of the 0? You can't just not initialise certain parts of an array.

Comment: About the question how much time it takes it will of course vary widely depending on platform. It should be very easy for you to test though.

Comment: He's basically wanting it to work like C where you basically have garbage (whatever happens to be in that memory) until you initialize it yourself. Java explicitly avoids this by initializing the memory when you allocate the array because an array is actually an object not just some contiguous memory.

Comment: i mean that e.g. new int[1000000] consists of 2 operations. first - memory allocation, second - JVM goes over the array and sets all elements to 0. But ususally we create an array then copy some data to it or use it in InputStream.read(byte[]). In both cases who cares what the initial values were?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev - no, it doesn't. An array in Java is an object on the heap rather than just a pointer to some memory on the stack/heap. It's .... just not the same thing.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be shocked if the JVM were smart enough to notice you were immediately writing over the array contents and omit the initialization.

Comment: Good point. If there were a confirmation of it I would say that  the case is closed.

Comment: Just create a large array and fill it with 0s using `java.util.Arrays.fill(char[] a, char val)`, measuring the time, to find out that the initialization time is negligible compared with the time required to fill the array with meaningful data.

Comment: NettyIO has some information about this matter.  Their I/O rates are so high (see Twitter, et al), that the zeroing out has significant thru-put impact.  They found a way to use `sun.misc.Unsafe` to create their own memory buffers that don't effectively "memset(0)".  If you have crazy performance requirements, read more about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've done some investigation. There is no legal way to create uninitialized array in Java. Even JNI NewXxxArray creates initialized arrays. So it is impossible to know exactly the cost of array zeroing. Nevertheless I've done some measurements:

1) 1000 byte arrays creation with different array size

```
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
//          byte[] a1 = new byte[1];
            byte[] a1 = new byte[1000000];
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
```

on my PC it gives < 1ms for byte[1] and ~500 ms for byte[1000000]. Sounds impressive to me.

2) We don't have a fast (native) method in JDK for filling arrays, Arrays.fill is too slow, so let's see at least how much 1000 copying of 1,000,000 size array takes with native System.arraycopy

```
    byte[] a1 = new byte[1000000];
    byte[] a2 = new byte[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(a1, 0, a2, 0, 1000000);
    }
```

It is 700 ms.

It gives me reasons to believe that a) creating long arrays is expensive b) it seems to be expensive because of useless initialization.

3) Let's take sun.misc.Unsafe http://www.javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/misc/Unsafe.html. It is protected from external usage but not too much

```
    Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(null);
```

Here is the cost of memory allocation test

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        long m = u.allocateMemory(1000000);
    }
```

It takes < 1 ms, if you remember, for new byte[1000000] it took 500ms.

4) Unsafe has no direct methods to work with arrays. It needs to know class fields, but reflection shows no fields in an array. There is not much info about arrays internals, I guess it is JVM / platform specific. Nevertheless, it is, like any other Java Object, header + fields. On my PC/JVM it looks like

```
header - 8 bytes
int length - 4 bytes
long bufferAddress - 8 bytes
```

Now, using Unsafe, I will create byte[10], allocate a 10 byte memory buffer and use it as my array's elements:

```
    byte[] a = new byte[10];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    long mem = unsafe.allocateMemory(10);
    unsafe.putLong(a, 12, mem);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

it prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 15, -114, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can see thay array's data are not initialized.

Now I'll change our array length (though it still points to 10 bytes memory)

```
    unsafe.putInt(a, 8, 1000000);
    System.out.println(a.length);
```

it shows 1000000. It was just to prove that the idea works.

Now performance test. I will create an empty byte array a1, allocate a buffer of 1000000 bytes, assign this buffer to a1 an set a1.length = 10000000

```
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        byte[] a1 = new byte[0];
        long mem1 = unsafe.allocateMemory(1000000);
        unsafe.putLong(a1, 12, mem);
        unsafe.putInt(a1, 8, 1000000);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
```

it takes 10ms.

5) There are malloc and alloc in C++, malloc just allocates memory block , calloc also initializes it with zeroes.

cpp

```
...
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_malloc(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint n) {
     malloc(n);
}
```

java

```
private native static void malloc(int n);

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    malloc(1000000);
}
```

results malloc - 78 ms; calloc - 468 ms

**Conclusions**

1. It seems that Java array creation is slow because of useless element zeroing.
2. We cannot change it, but Oracle can. No need to change anything in JLS, just add native methods to java.lang.reflect.Array like

   public static native xxx[] newUninitialziedXxxArray(int size);

for all primitive numeric types (byte - double) and char type. It could be used all over the JDK, like in java.util.Arrays

```
    public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) {
        int[] copy = Array.newUninitializedIntArray(newLength);
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length, newLength));
        ...
```

or java.lang.String

```
   public String concat(String str) {
        ...   
        char[] buf = Array.newUninitializedCharArray(count + otherLen);
        getChars(0, count, buf, 0);
        ...
```

Comment: Maybe it's just the hindsight, but this answer contains very little beyond worthless measurements and wrong conclusions drawn from wrong Unsafe usage. Some points: no warmup, measuring nanosecond events with `currentTimeMillis`, putting the return value of `allocate` (which is the block address) into the array and concluding that it's "uninitialized", ...

Comment: Block initialization and copying is aggressively optimized on Intel, and array initialization is aggressively optimized by the JIT (relying on SIMD instructions). The throughput for large blocks is some 30 GB/s (or was when I measured it on Core i7). That means you lose 1 µs to initialize 30,000 bytes---sometimes this maters, often it doesn't. It definitely constrains the area of usefulness of a dedicated optimization.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to move this to an answer because it probably should be.

An "Array" in java is not what you think it is. It's not just a pointer to a chunk of contiguous memory on the stack or heap.

An Array in Java is an Object just like everything else (except primitives) and is on the heap. When you call `new int[100000]` you're creating a new object just like every other object, and it gets initialized, etc.

The JLS provides all the specific info about this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html

So, no. You can't avoid "initializing" an array. That's just not how Java works. There's simply no such thing as uninitialized heap memory; many people call that a "feature" as it prevents you from accessing uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 2):

Java 9 actually starts to expose this via `jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray` method. It would actually require JDK.Unsupported module [declaration](https://dzone.com/articles/using-sunmiscunsafe-in-java-9-1).

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that O(n) cost of new int[n] could be a burden in some data structures or algorithms.

A way to have amortized O(1) cost of memory allocation in Java for a primitive array of size n is to do recycling of allocated arrays with an object pool or some other strategy. Recycled array can be considered "uninitialized" for the next allocation.