# Need of a faster array copy

Tags: java, arrays, performance, copy

After doing a bit of reading, I discovered that there are some differences in the ways you can copy arrays in java.  For my application I have a recursive tree of nodes, each containing a 2d board array (8x8).

Through profiler testing, the best thing I could come up with is the java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array) method, which uses the native System.arraycopy.

Even with this, I am spending 80% of my time creating new arrays.  If anyone has any ideas on how to speed this up I'd appreciate it.  Perhaps going to a 64 item array rather than an 8x8 would be faster.  I'll test this shortly.

Comment: Is there anyway to just pass references to the array and avoid the copying all together?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3

Comment: The best way is obliviously `System.arraycopy` which you already have used so now you are left with very less options one such would be trim down the array by removing null or empty elements, you may use `SparseMatrix` type data structure.

Comment: You could also encapsulate the array into a class, share a single array between multiple nodes, and only make a copy when needed (i.e. when a value is changed inside the array).

Comment: If it is the array allocation, you do your own allocation, using one single new T[8*8*1000].

Comment: May be it's reasonable to reduce array item's size. E.g. store byte rather than integer or a couple of bits to represent each element

Comment: is there a real performance problem, or are you just trying to make your app faster, although it's already fast enough? If the latter, then don't do anything.

Comment: Oracle's various Java implementations all use a native method under the hood to do the array copying. If you end up doing 8 arraycopy's you might get a performance improvement by using a 1d array, implementing your own 2d subscripting ala @JoopEggen's comment, and doing a single arraycopy. Clarity will suffer however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently done an investigation in this regard (see my answer to my own question at [Is there any way to create a primitive array without initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780350/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-primitive-array-without-initialization), it could have been named "Why Array.copyOf is so slow" or "Why Java is so slow") and even sent an RFE to Oracle. The main idea is that Java spends too much time for useless array initialization. This is about how Arrays.copyOf could have been faster.

Comment: right, it was only to prove the concept, the only thing we can do now is to keep in mind that new byte[n] is expensive. I am going to write a JNI CreateUninitializedByteArray and see how this idea works in real life.

Comment: jni overhead is too high, it most likely won't payoff. I think you should find a way to improve the algorithm (as i stated below)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are spending 80% time copying arrays means one of two things:

1. array copying is too slow;
2. you are barely doing anything else beside copying arrays.

Your copying performance may already be cutting-edge; consider the architecture of your application instead, try reducing the amount of copied data.

Answer (score 3):

System.arraycopy() is the best if your code needs to be clear.

However, if performance is becomming a real bottleneck, you may look at:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-using-direct-memory-java

Answer (score 1):

you need an algorithmic improvement. (are you doing a min max chess algorithm ?)

A possibility is to just copy the reference to each 8x8 array and add a 'shared' flag to each array. Then copy the array only if you actually do change the array. As long you are not changing all of the arrays, this would reduce copying a lot.

Another variant would be to find a more compact representation for your 8x8 array (e.g. some bit magic).

What do your array entries contain ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. An 8x8 array is essentially 9 array allocations and 1 initialization. With the use of a size 64 array rather than 8x8, the allocation is only once and I can now skip the initialization.

I will, however, look at other ways to improve the speed ... as faster array copies means I can make more nodes :D.

Thanks everyone