# Java fastest way to cut an array into an uneven matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to cut an array at a fixed dimension and put the result in another array
essentially creating an uneven matrix

I've found this solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixize(2,     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));
}

public static Object[][] matrixize(int cutat, Object... data) {
    int rows = (int) Math.ceil(data.length / (double) cutat);
    Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, cutat * i, Math.min(data.length, cutat * (i + 1)));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

As expected the result is:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

- There is a faster way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your code is pretty much fine and it seems to be quite fast, the below code is working a **bit** faster:

> Your code average execution time(10 try) : **19158 nanoseconds**
>
> Below code average execution time(10 try): **14891 nanoseconds**

```
public Object[][] matrixize(int cutat, Object... data) {
    int rows = (int) Math.ceil(data.length / (double) cutat);
    Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows][cutat];
    int matrIndex = 0, i = 0;
    for (; i < data.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < cutat; j++) {
            matrix[matrIndex][j] = data[i];
            i++;
        }
        matrIndex++;
        --i;
    }
    if(i<data.length) matrix[matrIndex] = new Object[]{data[i]};
    return matrix;
}
```

Output:

```
jshell> System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixize(2,     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

I tried to understand what could be the reason for this difference and found that java `Arrays.copy` are a little slow then creating fixed size arrays and then copying the data

[Need of a faster array copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902079/need-of-a-faster-array-copy)

Also, if you will see in Arrays `copyOfRange` method, couple of statements are getting executed, while to copy we just need to copy the reference of existing variables from one array to another.

Comment: Sorry to say this: 1. your solution is not correct, please try more test cases; 2. your solution is copying around the references and when performance comes first, we should use index to locate the elements as OldCurmudgeon mentioned, which is also what `substring` does to save the moving-around overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You cant really get significantly faster if you really need to use arrays.

However, if you are ok using `List<List<>>` instead then you could avoid all of that array copying which would be a significant bonus if these arrays can become large.

Note that with this solution writes to the resulting matrix would **write through to the original data** which could be a good thing or a bad thing.

```
private static class ArraySlice<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    private final T[] data;
    private final int start;
    private final int length;

    public ArraySlice(T[] data, int start, int length) {
        this.data = data;
        this.start = start;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        if(index > length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds");
        return data[start + index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return length;
    }
}

public static <T> List<List<T>> matrixize(int cutat, T... data) {
    List<List<T>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i += cutat) {
        matrix.add(new ArraySlice(data, i, Math.min(cutat, data.length - i)));
    }
    return matrix;
}

public void test() {
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = matrixize(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    System.out.println(matrix);
}
```

This prints:

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]

Answer (score 1):

If it is about raw speed, you can make it marginally faster by letting it create fixed-size arrays first ([`copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) accepts "outlier" `to` argument), and truncate the last element separately when needed, using some modulo check perhaps.
Also, that magic with `rows` can be done with integer-arithmetics: `int rows=(data.length+cutat-1)/cutat;`.

Something like:

```
int rows=(data.length+cutat-1)/cutat;
Object[][] matrix=new Object[rows][];
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i+=cutat)
  matrix[i]=Arrays.copyOfRange(data,i,i+cutat);
int mod=data.length % cutat;
if(mod>0)
  matrix[rows-1]=Arrays.copyOfRange(matrix[rows-1],0,mod);
```

But I do not say it is really going to be "faster" than the original, it is more like a different style.

If you have huge amounts of data, it is probably faster to keep it unaltered, and use simple `[x+y*width]`-style indexing to access elements in "2D way" from 1D storage.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an answer, I am trying to clarify severals things and it might be helpful for your optimisation.

First, Aman Chhabra's point and analysis is okay but not accurate and his solution firstly not properly tested and over-cross the array bound for not testing the array in the inner loop and also the last line is incorrect.

Second, OldCurmudgeon provided a pretty insightful view we always encounter to save time and improve performance both in **space** and **time**. One typical example is what we do with `substring`, we share it but just use `offset` and `length` to identify the `sub` avoid **copying** and **extra space** being wasted.

**We share the data behind and encapsulate the details in an object/instance but provide essential/necessary interfaces for usages.**

OldCurmudgeon has already provided a demo for this kind of design. You should follow the idea and mark the answer of his.

Anyway, here is a demo to test the thought of Aman Chhabra's solution which proves strongly that your solution is faster though Aman Chhabra mentioned lots of possible overhead, but I just believe the random test cases can only prove the fact.

```
public class CutArrayToMatrix {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        test(CutArrayToMatrix::matrixizeByCopy);
        test(CutArrayToMatrix::matrixize);
    }

    private static void test(BiConsumer<Integer, Object[]> biConsumer) {
        int testTimes = 50;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Long start;
        List<Long> timer = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < testTimes; ++i) {
            int N = new Random().nextInt(500) + 100_000;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                list.add(new Random().nextInt());
            }
            Object[][] oo1 = matrixize(30, list.toArray());
            Object[][] oo2 = matrixizeByCopy(30, list.toArray());
            assert oo1.length == oo2.length : "length not equal";
            assert oo1[oo1.length - 1].length == oo2[oo2.length - 1].length : "last not equal";
            start = System.nanoTime();
            biConsumer.accept(30, list.toArray());
            timer.add(System.nanoTime() - start);
        }
        System.out.println(timer.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(Long::longValue)));
    }

    public static Object[][] matrixizeByCopy(Integer cutat, Object... data) {
        int rows = (int) Math.ceil(data.length / (double) cutat);
        Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows][cutat];
        int i = 0;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        while (i < data.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cutat; ++j) {
                matrix[rowIndex][j] = data[i++];
                if (i == data.length) return matrix;
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static Object[][] matrixize(int cutat, Object... data) {
        int rows = (int) Math.ceil(data.length / (double) cutat);
        Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            matrix[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, cutat * i, Math.min(data.length, cutat * (i + 1)));
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

After some local tests, one of the typical result is:

```
// Aman Chhabra's solution (actually I followed his thought but fixed the bugs in his code)
LongSummaryStatistics{count=50, sum=666080821, min=5757846, average=13321616.420000, max=33013518}
// your solution;
LongSummaryStatistics{count=50, sum=329080566, min=1709920, average=6581611.320000, max=57146002}
```