# Avoid array initialization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, unsafe

Is it possible to avoid array zeroing/initialization in Java?

I need to quickly allocate fresh byte arrays of fixed length that will completely be filled with predefined data. Therefore, I don't need the JVM to automatically zero the array on instantiation and I certainly don't mind if the array contains junk. All I need is constant time array allocation, which unfortunately becomes O(n) due to the mentioned zeroing issue.

Would using unsafe help?

Comment: You could do it like netty, and do manual pooling & reference counting http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.html + http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/ReferenceCounted.html#release()  - the duplicate isn't obvious (and I don't think a good duplicate) but if you click through a bit you could have found in like http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/ the part about "Interesting use cases
Avoid initialization" - edit: hmm not in there, but in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13785284/995891

Comment: Another thing you could consider if you just need an array for temporary purposes, have a `ThreadLocal` store them. Gives you one per thread and is safe and fast as long as you use thread pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM always initializes arrays. But you can reuse the same array and it will be initialized once.

Comment: Sadly I can't because these arrays are held on to for an undefined period of time by an asynchronous networking library. Reusing them results in overwriting partially unsent messages. That's why I was hoping for a solution that would quickly allocate new arrays without zeroing them.

Comment: If you can know when the library is done with the buffer you can use array pooling. I.e. create a pool of arrays and give/return them from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

The class `sun.misc.Unsafe` is officially undocumented.

From http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

> Avoid initialization
>
> allocateInstance method can be useful when you need to skip object
>   initialization phase or bypass security checks in constructor or you
>   want instance of that class but don't have any public constructor.

Some resources indicate its removal from Java 9.

Comment: How do you allocate an on-heap array with a predefined length? I haven't found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. What kind of application do you have that array initialization became a performance bottleneck?
2. In response to "Sadly I can't because these arrays are held on to for an undefined period of time by an asynchronous networking library. Reusing them results in overwriting partially unsent messages.":
   Then use a pool and reuse only arrays that are not currently in use. You will have to manage that, though. So, is array creation **really** that much of an issue?

Comment: 1. Ticker plant 2. Using a pool might be possible. Thanks for the idea.