# How to access part of a primitive array without copying it in java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, buffer

Well, I know that there are two similar questions but mine is different:

How do I get the subset of a primitive array without copying it?

Why?
I have to read many large "files" (~20M) read via stdin. These files have inside a JPG files embedded. These JPG files are used for some calculations. I need to keep the original file, while I use the embedded JPGs to decide to keep the original file at all.

For that I would like to get the subset (JPG) of the byte array (original file). I want to use this subset array with a 3rd party library (OpenCV).

The most close solution is: Arrays.asList(array).subList(x, y).
But this solution doesn't work for primitive arrays. I am trying to improve performance by not copying the array and not using wrapper classes.

Are there really no ways of grabbing subset of a primitive array?

By the way, ByteBuffer.wrap(array, position, length).toArray() returns the original full byte array.

---

Edit: Sorry for forgetting to tell you that I am getting these files from a device and not disk. Therefore, I need to capture the whole thing first into memory. Then decide to keep it on disk or not.

Comment: Guava has `Ints.asList()` (same for other primitive types).

Comment: Why read the entire file into memory in the first place? Just read/skip to the JPG part, read that, then make your decision.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to decide to keep the whole thing based on some properties of JPG. The byte array comes from a device. I don't want to save on the disk to reduce IO burden on the disk, as I will have lot's of such files to process. Maybe 1000s.

Comment: Can you read each file into several arrays? E.g. one for prefix, the next one for jpg. If you decide to save the file, just write from each array sequentially. Pass the jpg array to the third party library.

Comment: I can't. The device will capture the picture and transmit over USB/PTP interface. I get a byte stream. I need to store it in the memory. There are 3 JPG files embedded within each RAW picture file (lossless compressed TIFF). I want to keep the RAW file, if JPG file has certain properties. I want to reduce unnecessary disk IO and memory consumption. My application would also work by simply copying JPG byte array into new a memory space. But it is out of principle that I think I  should be able to reference a subset of an existing larger array. I am curious, if I can achieve this somehow.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Why wouldn't this work: you get a byte stream, you start reading into `tiffStartArray`, then when JPG1 starts you read it into `jpg1Array`, and so on. You end up with several arrays but there's no duplication among them. You pass jpg arrays to the third-party library. If you decide to save the file, you write `tiffStartArray` into it, then `jpg1Array`, then ...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I now understand your question and that should be a workaround solution I didn't consider. I was thinking more like a C/C++ point of view, simply addressing same memory space with another array object. Thanks a lot. However, for the sake of the stackexchange, the main question is still not answered. My search on the internet points out that this might be a limitation by Java implementation. I would accept your answer though if you put it as a an answer below until a more direct solution is provided. Your answer works for me but not for overlapping subarrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array reference in Java (speaking about HotSpot JVM), you pass a reference to a memory region which must have a particular layout: object header, array length, then array contents. You should somehow put header and length at the start of your smaller JPG array, thus "corrupting" your bigger array.

All in all, I think, this can be done using `sun.misc.Unsafe` or JNI, knowledge of the details of your JVM (32 or 64 bits, with compressed oops or not), luck so that no GC will happen amidst yout trick, saving and then restoring the "corrupted" bytes, but it's extremely fragile and prone to errors.

Comment: I looked into JNI and several sources claim that one needs to access a Java array via JNI only through available methods. I looked briefly into available methods but I didn't find a way to "create" an array object with custom fields. sun.misc.Unsafe is considered to be removed with Java 9 and it is highly discouraged. Yet, many libraries use it for better performance. sun.misc.Unsafe can actually reach all those fields. Here is a nice analysis of Unsafe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780350/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-primitive-array-without-initialization/13785284#13785284